# fatal exception in android that cannot find class

Tags: java, android

> 03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814): Process: com.example.rb, PID: 15814
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/example/rb/Dashboard;
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):    at com.example.rb.MainActivity$1$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:157)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):    at com.example.rb.MainActivity$1$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):    ... 4 more
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.rb.Dashboard" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.rb-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):    ... 8 more
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.rb.Dashboard
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):        ... 10 more
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.rb.Dashboard
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):        ... 9 more
>   03-09 14:51:26.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15814):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

this is my logcat while i run my application.

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
                        pd.setTitle("Authenticating...");
                        pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
                        pd.setCancelable(false);
                        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
                        pd.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {



                        try{
                            username=etloginname.getText().toString();
                            password=etpass.getText().toString();


                            CallLogin.usernameparam=etloginname.getText().toString();                           
                            CallLogin.userpasswordparam=etpass.getText().toString();



                            rslt = "START";

                            CallLogin c = new CallLogin();
                            c.join();
                            c.start();

                            while(rslt=="START"){
                                Thread.sleep(10);
                            }



                                JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(rslt);



                             String[] No = new String[jsonArr.length()];
                             String[] Responsibility_Center = new String[jsonArr.length()];
                             //String[] Name = new String[jsonArr.length()];


                             SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++)

                            {

                                JSONObject jc = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

                                No[i] = jc.getString("No");
                                Responsibility_Center[i]=jc.getString("Responsibility_Center");
                                //Name[i] = jc.getString("Name");

                            }
                            editor.clear();
                            editor.putBoolean("hasLoggedIn", true);
                            editor.putString("userno",No[0]);
                            editor.putString("Responsibility_Center",Responsibility_Center[0]);

                           // editor.putString("firstname",Name[0]);
                            Intent in1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Dashboard.class); //exception throws here.
                            //in.putExtra("dashusername", Name[0]);

                            in1.putExtra("userid", No[0]);
                            in1.putExtra("Responsibility_Center", Responsibility_Center[0]);
                            startActivity(in1);

                            finish();
                            // Commit the edits!
                            editor.commit();

                            }catch(final Exception ex){
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Id OR Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                     }
                                });
                            }

                        return null;
                    }

};
```

Comment: you missing Dashboard.class. is it from other project or library?

Comment: procedure is wrong. update UI in postExecute. do in background is used to perform large operations like parsing.

Comment: @Shadow that exactly what ive done

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira no it is in my Project

Comment: as shadow says, you need move your SharedPreferences code until bracket before return null to onPostExecute

Comment: Make sure you declared class in manifest

Comment: @DhruvTrivedi No.. you are trying to update UI in the backgroundthread ,try it in onPostExecute method

Comment: guys still not working

Comment: what not working? update your code what you done and logcat too orelse can't know.